# Build job on Jenkins pipeline returns a null objet when wait is set to false

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jobs

I have a pipeline in Jenkins whose first stage is about triggering another job with the `build` function. I want to have the **RunWrapper** object back from the build function, but it returns a `null` object when the `wait` paramater is set to `false`.

Basically, in this case the `build` function returns the correct object type :

```
stage('Trigger Another Job With Propagate') {
   steps {
      script {
         triggeredJob = build(job: 'Tiggered_Job', wait: true)

         echo "${triggeredJob.getClass()}"
         // correct object type
      }
   }
}
```

But when we don't want to wait the job to finish before stepping into the next stages, a null object is returned :

```
stage('Trigger Another Job With Propagate') {
   steps {
      script {
         triggeredJob = build(job: 'Tiggered_Job', wait: false)

         echo "${triggeredJob.getClass()}"
         // null object type
      }
   }
}
```

I think that behavior is not normal, we should be able to use the object in any case.

Comment: Why do you want to access the Job if you are not waiting?

Comment: Because I want to parent Job to continue next stages while the child Job is also running. I can't use parallel { } because the child Job already has stages executing in parallel, and Jenkins doesn't know how to execute parallel of parallel tasks as far as I know

Comment: Same situation here. In my naive phantasies I had expected to get something like a "promise" that would be filled with job info as and when it became available. But `null` is really a hefty disillusionment ;)