# In Jenkins/Groovy is it possible to get the build ID from an asynchronously triggered build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Running `build(job: 'path/to/job')` in a Jenkins pipeline script triggers provided `@job` in a blocking way, i.e. it triggers a build and waits for it to finish and returns a `RunWrapper` object.
Setting `wait: false` will not wait but also doesn't return anything at all, so I don't have any reference to the triggered build.
Is there a way to trigger a build asynchronously *and* know what build had been triggered?

(related: [Build job on Jenkins pipeline returns a null objet when wait is set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73303527/build-job-on-jenkins-pipeline-returns-a-null-objet-when-wait-is-set-to-false))

Comment: How would you expect it to work? For example if the triggered job is stuck in the queue for a period of time then there is no triggered build. You have to wait to get that information.

Comment: In that case I could either get a queue ID or make use of another `wait`-semantic, e.g. `await_started=true`. Currently I have nothing to refer to, so I'm triggering a build into the void..

Comment: There is no such thing as `queue ID`. The only thing you can do is query all the triggered job builds and identify your build - the requires the ability to distinguished your specific build in terms of parameters values or by the trigged job, ill post an example as answer.

Comment: well, at least there is a `'queue/item/%(number)d/` endpoint in the Jenkins API and you can access the queue stack as well..

Comment: Using the Jenkins-Python API you can also do exactly that: trigger a build, get a `QueueID` and wait for the build to be started. But unfortunately via API I can't provide the 'triggered by' info..

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the build step doesn't return anything in case you don't wait for the build is that the build might get stuck in the queue (so there  is no build number) or just get stuck in some state that doesn't allow to grab the build id quickly.

You can overcome this by implementing the logic by yourself. For example, assuming you are wiling to wait until the job starts, you can create a function like the following:

```groovy
def getTriggeredBuild(job) {
    // Run while the job did not start 
    while (true) { 
        // Search for the current build as the cause trigger
        def message = "upstream project \"${JOB_NAME}\" build number ${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        for (build in Jenkins.instance.getItem(job).getBuilds()) {
            // Iterate over all builds and find the one that was triggred by this build
            if(build.getCauses().any{ it.getShortDescription().contains(message) }) {
                return build 
            }
        }
        sleep 5
    }
}
```

This function can reside in a shared library, making it available for all your pipelines, or it can reside within your Jenkinsfile, but then an administrator will have to approve usage of some of the functions (not needed in the shared library).

Usage will be strait forward:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {  
               script {
                   def jobName = 'triggred_job'
                   build job: jobName, wait: false
    
                   // Get the build that was triggered
                   def build = getTriggeredBuild(jobName)
                   println(build.number)
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The waiting logic of the function can be modified according to your needs.

Comment: While that might work if you can be sure your job only triggers one other build it will fail as soon as you trigger multiple jobs in parallel, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why should there be a problem? You are searching for the exact build number (of the caller job) that triggered the build - on multiple executions each execution will have its own build id, so there should not be any collision.

Comment: The caller can trigger multiple builds (e.g. to build a set of differently configured upstream artifacts). And if you now need to somehow operate on _multiple_ builds before they have been completed, you need some sort of reference (either queue id or build id)

Comment: If you trigger multiple builds of that job you will have to add an additional identifier for the triggered build like a value of a parameter or alike.